# Error ITMS-9000 name that contains leading or trailing characters

Tags: xcode

Newbee here...
I'm having problems when submiting my app to the AppStore. I did everything at developer.apple.com until the message "Waiting for upload appears" and then when trying to submit the app through Application Loader I get this message:

Error ITMS-9000:"Your package contains a file"Speed Clicker .app/Speed Clicker" with a name that contains leading or trailing characters." 
at SoftwareAssets/SoftwareAsset (MZltmspSoftwareAssetPackage)'
Could not start delivery: all transport failed diagnostics

Can anyone help me out with this? Don´t know how to solve this:(
Any help appreciated! Thanxz in advance!

/Peter

Answer (score 1):

Remove the spaces from the Target or Product name in the Build Settings

```
Speed Clicker .app/Speed Clicker
```

Comment: Hi, where do i enter and change it? Should i enter under Packaging  and then change the info.plist file or product Name. My project and targets to the left are both written Speed Clicker

Comment: Under build settings search for product name and check you've got no spaces there. Basically you can't have spaces in that name :)
Have a look around for any and removed them!

Comment: Still not working! Have tried renaming the app so it says SpeedClicker everywhere under project,targets etc. One thing though at the button after renaming  it says SpeedClicker .app (there is a space between SpeedClicker and app coming when renaming). Hmm still stuck....

Comment: "at the button" - What do you mean here?

Comment: I mean to the left under Products, SpeedClicker .app and SpeedClicker Tests xctest

Comment: @user3422822 Can you add a screen shot to your question :)

Comment: also i have noticed that when i renamed the project it  says Speed Clicker 2014 at the top beside the simulator options. Speed Clicker 2014 was my first name when i started building the app. Then i changed it to Speed Clicker.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any spaces after the name of your target? Select it, and then press 'Enter' just to edit it and make sure. I only say that as your project name has a space after it `SpeedClicker .xcodeproj`

Comment: I don´t see any space of the filename under Targets.Also I don´t know how to select it and change it to take away the space at the top . SpeedClicker .xcodeproj

Comment: I meant click on the target under the "TARGETS" list, and then press enter this will allow you to edit it. I doubt you'd be able to see the space thats why I suggest you check to make sure.

Comment: I´ve clicked the 2 files under Targets (SpeedClicker and SpeedClicker Tests and pressed enter,nothing new happens. Confusing and irritating not to find the solution. Why can´t i change the top name of the project SpeedClicker xcodeproj?

Comment: Try going to `SpeedClicker .xcodeproj` in Finder, and then right clicking and `Show package contents`, then find `project.pbxproj` and open in `TextEdit` (or a text edit of your choice) and then search for ` .app` (thats a space dot app). Or use [paste bin](http://pastebin.com/) and dump a copy of the `project.pbxproj` in there and I'll have a look :)

Comment: what do u mean by space dot app? Where can i find that file .app? I´m looking now inside.Sorry can´t send you the project cause i´ve implemented adcode inside.

Comment: I appreciate you help anyway :)

Comment: As in search for the text ' .app' inside the 'project.pbxproj'. The only other option I can suggest it to create a new Xcode project and copy the code over :) Good luck!